# How to extract zip codes from multipolygons?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a geodataframe containing utility company service areas. Each geodataframe has a multipolygon to represent the area to which the company provides service. I am trying to build a dataframe where these multipolygons can be represented by zip codes.

The dataframe looks like this:[image]

The goal would be for example the first utility company, if the geometry overlaps 10 zip codes, the new dataframe would have ten rows with the same utility company name and ID.

I have reverse geocoded single longitude and latitude coordinates before, but have never worked with polygons. Most of the resources on the web involve turning zip codes into polygons, not the other way around.

Edit: zip code geodataframe below[image]

Comment: Find an open source data set of zip code polygons. I was able to find one for my area fairly quickly. Then you can do a spatial join between the service areas and zip codes. If you find such a dataset, post an example of your current gdf and the zip code one and I'll help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just updated the post to include a zip code .gdb from esri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically all you need to do is use gpd.sjoin. If you only want the zip code from the other data frame, you would just use something like this:

```
with_zip = gpd.sjoin(utility_gdf,zipcode_gdf[['ZIP_CODE','geometry']],how='left',op='intersects')
```

See for further reference:
[Merging Data - GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html)

**Edit:**

After looking at the geometries, the two datasets are in fact using different coordinate reference systems. Getting the two crs to match up is a 2 step process;

1. Transform the crs
2. Set the crs type on the geoseries

But first, you need to figure out what crs each data set is currently using.
To find what crs each gdf is using, just type

```
gdf.geometry.crs
```

If either of the datasets have a 'NoneType' crs, you're going to have to do some googling to figure out what crs it actually is using.

Once you figure out which crs you have, you then transform it.
Here's a pretty good thread on transforming crs:
[GIS stack exchange thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/transforming-shapely-polygon-and-multipolygon-objects)

Then once you have the actual geometry datapoints transformed to a new crs, you then need to set the appropriate crs type of the geoseries. For instance, if you transformed gdf1.geometry from "EPSG:2966" to "EPSG:4236", you would then call:

```
gdf1.set_crs("EPSG:4236",inplace=True,allow_override=True)
```

And *then* you can retry the merge operation.

Comment: Thanks again for following up. I ran the same exact code and was met with this error: 

<ipython-input-5-0052b3a1e8b8>:1: UserWarning: CRS mismatch between the CRS of left geometries and the CRS of right geometries.
Use `to_crs()` to reproject one of the input geometries to match the CRS of the other.
Left CRS: EPSG:3857
Right CRS: EPSG:4326

Comment: @NateLeMay, Just edited the original with some additional info.

Comment: @NateLeMay Rad! I'm glad it worked, I was worried about effectively communicating the procedure.

Comment: Worked great! I didn't realize the geospatial capabilities of python. Can't wait to dig more into it